# C# Binaryformatter deserialize to string?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, flat-file

I am serializing only one data to MyFile.bin file, now i have to deserialize it to a string or Int and add +1 with current value and save it again, In order to do this how to deserialize the value to Int or String variable?

**Code**

```
public void saveMember()
{

  string pathMemberPk = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"../memberDataPk.bin");

  if (!File.Exists(pathMemberPk)) {

     memberPk = 0001;
     memberPkString = memberPk.ToString();

     IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
     Stream streamPk = new FileStream(pathMemberPk, FileMode.Create);
     formatter.Serialize(streamPk,this.memberPkString);   

   }else{

     using (FileStream streamIn = File.OpenRead("f://MyFile.bin"))
     {
         string pk;
         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
         string pkk = (pk)formatter.Deserialize(streamIn).ToString();
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**I Solved Myself**

```
public void saveMember()
{

  string pathMemberPk = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"../memberDataPk.bin");

  if (!File.Exists(pathMemberPk)) {

     memberPk = 0001;
     memberPkString = memberPk.ToString();

     IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
     Stream streamPk = new FileStream(pathMemberPk, FileMode.Create);
     formatter.Serialize(streamPk,this.memberPkString);   

   }else{

     using (FileStream streamIn = File.OpenRead("f://MyFile.bin"))
     {
         IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();                   
         object obj = formatter.Deserialize(streamIn);
         memberPk = Convert.ToInt32(obj); //to INT
        memberPk = Convert.ToString(obj); //To String

         Console.WriteLine(memberPk);
      }

   }
}
```